# Error While Deployment; User Code Not Handled

Tags: gpio, pi-2, windows-iot

I am a newbie to RPi, I deployed my first app using VS15 in RPi2 WindowsIoT Core. at deployment the error shows(The error place is shown in the comments):

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in IoTTest1.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Failed to open a handle to the device.

Additional information: Element not found.

Failed to open a handle to the device.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

The code is as follows:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private const int LED_PIN = 7;
    private GpioPinValue ledPin_value;
    private GpioPin ledPin;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitGPIO();
    }

    private void InitGPIO()
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
        if (gpio == null)
        {
            GpioStatus.Text = "There is no GPIO controller on this device.";
            return;
        }

        ledPin = gpio.OpenPin(LED_PIN);   //This is where the compiler stops
        ledPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        ledPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

        GpioStatus.Text = "GPIO pins initialized correctly.";
    }

    private void buttonPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
     //just for button functions on the app.
    private async void OnSwitch_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ledPin_value == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {
            ledPin_value = GpioPinValue.High;
            ColourGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            ledPin_value = GpioPinValue.Low;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            ledPin_value = GpioPinValue.High;
        }

    }

    private void KillSwitch_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ledPin_value == GpioPinValue.High)
        {
            ledPin_value = GpioPinValue.Low;
            ColourGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I need Help!